# How to ignore a Foreign Key restriction on delete?

Tags: sqlite, c#-4.0, sql-delete

I have to tables and I am using Foreign Key restriction set that no action is taken if I try to delete a record in the first table that is used as FK in the second table. I want this behavior.

The problem is that when I have a many T-SQL like that:

```
strTSQL = "delete or ignore from Ficheros where IDFichero = 28"
strTSQL = strTSQL + ";delete or ignore from Ficheros where IDFichero = 27"
```

IF the first T-SQL fails the next query is not execute. I would like to execute the next query although the first is failed.

In the insert I can use:

insert or ignore in ....

In this cases, if I try to insert a record that violates a unique constraint ignore the error and continue with the next T-SQL, but with the delete I don't find the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could execute the DELETE statements individually and ignore the FK constraint error.

Alternively, check beforehand whether a constriant violation would occur:

```sql
DELETE FROM Ficheros
WHERE IDFichero IN (27, 28, ...)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ChildTable
                  WHERE ChildTable.IDFichero = Ficheros.IDFichero)
```

Comment: Yes, to delete one by one each statement it's an option, but I need N round trips to the database. Really no matter because SQLite s a local db, but I was looking for another solution. Also, if one user check if exsits and check that 28 is not exists but before the delete another user set the relationship of 28, then I get the same problem.